# How to display Power BI Report Server reports in ReportViewer control in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer, power-bi-report-server

We have an ASP.NET MVC application and we are already using SSRS reports in it. These SSRS reports are displayed to end users using the `ReportViewer` control.

We just started using PowerBI reports. These reports are deployed using PowerBI server.

Can we display PowerBI reports (and dashboards) from PowerBI report server in a `ReportViewer` control? If yes - how?

Please note that we do not want to display reports from Power BI service (and hence Azure hosting solution is not applicable). Rather we need to show them from PowerBI Report Server.

We also tried using iframe, but then it asks for credentials when the report is opened in iframe, which we don't want to display to the end user.

So there are questions below:
1: Does reportviewer control supports PowerBI reports ?
2: If not, is there any alternative to display PowerBI reports from MVC application (using on premise Power BI server)?
3: If we have to use Iframe, then is there any way to pass credentials to src tag in iframe, silently, instead of asking it to user ?

Answer (score 1):

Answering to my own question.

We had a discussions with Microsoft team, and as of today on July 2023, they do not have any such control, where we can display Power BI reports from standalone server, into MVC application.

So it appears that we are left with only option (with stand alone Power BI server) is to display reports in iframe. However on opening the page first time, it will ask for the credentials.